# Why in some cases it makes sense to multiply Stdev by the Sqrt(N)?

Tags: standard-deviation, volatility-forecasting

I found an example when a so-called `volatility index` is calculated by multiplication of a `sample standard deviation` by the `square root of the sample size`, see [here](https://www.bitmex.com/app/index/.BVOL24H)

Does it make a good sense, and why? If it does, why not `Sqrt(N-1)`?